# Where is my stylesheet located?

Tags: theming

I would like to make small css changes such as h1 and various font, background colors and divs etc. I am using Newsflash theme on Drupal 7 and I have searched and searched my folders thus: sites> all> themes> newsflash> css> **local.css**

I can probably override things here but I would prefer to go to the source stylesheet if it exists.  Does it exist?  If not, is **local.css** the right place to write my changes?

Comment: I would rather suggest you to create a base theme from Newsflash and mark your css changes in that or just add your own css file. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/is-it-possible-to-add-css-to-theme-without-a-subtheme?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Go to **/admin/config/development/performance**

Uncheck Aggregate and compress css files

[image]

Now with your browser right click and inspect element, hover mouse over the .css file and it will tell you where it is at.

[image]

If it's coming from a contrib module, you should add your css on your theme's CSS file (in your case being local.css), as when you update that contrib module, it will lose the changes.

As you can see in my screenshot, that is coming from my theme's homepage.css file.

**PS:** After you're done, remember to turn back on (check-mark) Aggregate and compress css files in Performance.